# Access denied error when archiving WAL during postgresql 9.5 replication setup

Tags: postgresql, replication, windows, postgresql-9.5

I want to setup Postgres replication on Windows. I followed the given youtube url step by step: [youtube video](https://youtube.com/watch?v=Zq4zS0ZbXsc).

For `archive_command` I use this:

```
archive_command = 'copy "%p" "\\\\ip-address of sharable drive\\soft\\\wal\\%f"'
```

but when I look into the folder, folder is empty and WAL files are not transferred from `pg_xlog` to the desired location; it gives error access denied. In `services.msc` postgresql log on as network services.

[image: services.msc]

error log:

```
2018-04-30 16:34:06 IST LOG:  archive command failed with exit code 1
2018-04-30 16:34:06 IST DETAIL:  The failed archive command was: copy %\ip-address of sharable drive\soft\SUJITwal\000000010000000E00000083
2018-04-30 16:34:07 IST LOG:  archive command failed with exit code 1
2018-04-30 16:34:07 IST DETAIL:  The failed archive command was: copy %\ip-address of sharable drive1\soft\SUJITwal\000000010000000E00000083
2018-04-30 16:34:08 IST LOG:  archive command failed with exit code 1
2018-04-30 16:34:08 IST DETAIL:  The failed archive command was: copy %\ip-address of sharable drive\soft\SUJITwal\000000010000000E00000083
2018-04-30 16:34:08 IST WARNING:  archiving transaction log file "000000010000000E00000083" failed too many times, will try again later
2018-04-30 16:35:08 IST LOG:  archive command failed with exit code 1
2018-04-30 16:35:08 IST DETAIL:  The failed archive command was: copy %\ip-address of sharable drive\soft\SUJITwal\000000010000000E00000083
2018-04-30 16:35:09 IST LOG:  archive command failed with exit code 1
2018-04-30 16:35:09 IST DETAIL:  The failed archive command was: copy %\ip-address of sharable drive\soft\SUJITwal\000000010000000E00000083
2018-04-30 16:35:10 IST LOG:  archive command failed with exit code 1
2018-04-30 16:35:10 IST DETAIL:  The failed archive command was: copy %\ip-address of sharable drive\soft\SUJITwal\000000010000000E00000083
2018-04-30 16:35:10 IST WARNING:  archiving transaction log file "000000010000000E00000083" failed too many times, will try again later
2018-04-30 16:36:10 IST LOG:  archive command failed with exit code 1
2018-04-30 16:36:10 IST DETAIL:  The failed archive command was: copy %\ip-address of sharable drive\soft\SUJITwal\000000010000000E00000083
2018-04-30 16:36:11 IST LOG:  archive command failed with exit code 1
2018-04-30 16:36:11 IST DETAIL:  The failed archive command was: copy %\ip-address of sharable drive\soft\SUJITwal\000000010000000E00000083
2018-04-30 16:36:12 IST LOG:  archive command failed with exit code 1
2018-04-30 16:36:12 IST DETAIL:  The failed archive command was: copy %\ip-address of sharable drive\soft\SUJITwal\000000010000000E00000083
2018-04-30 16:36:12 IST WARNING:  archiving transaction log file "000000010000000E00000083" failed too many times, will try again later
2018-04-30 16:37:12 IST LOG:  archive command failed with exit code 1
2018-04-30 16:37:12 IST DETAIL:  The failed archive command was: copy %\ip-address of sharable drive\soft\SUJITwal\000000010000000E00000083
2018-04-30 16:37:13 IST LOG:  archive command failed with exit code 1
2018-04-30 16:37:13 IST DETAIL:  The failed archive command was: copy %\ip-address of sharable drive\soft\SUJITwal\000000010000000E00000083
2018-04-30 16:37:15 IST LOG:  archive command failed with exit code 1
2018-04-30 16:37:15 IST DETAIL:  The failed archive command was: copy %\ip-address of sharable drive\soft\SUJITwal\000000010000000E00000083
2018-04-30 16:37:15 IST WARNING:  archiving transaction log file "000000010000000E00000083" failed too many times, will try again later 
2018-04-30 16:38:15 IST LOG:  archive command failed with exit code 1
2018-04-30 16:38:15 IST DETAIL:  The failed archive command was: copy %\ip-address of sharable drive\soft\SUJITwal\000000010000000E00000083
2018-04-30 16:38:16 IST LOG:  archive command failed with exit code 1
2018-04-30 16:38:16 IST DETAIL:  The failed archive command was: copy %\ip-address of sharable drive\soft\SUJITwal\000000010000000E00000083
2018-04-30 16:38:17 IST LOG:  archive command failed with exit code 1
2018-04-30 16:38:17 IST DETAIL:  The failed archive command was: copy %\ip-address of sharable drive\soft\SUJITwal\000000010000000E00000083
2018-04-30 16:38:17 IST WARNING:  archiving transaction log file "000000010000000E00000083" failed too many times, will try again later
2018-04-30 16:39:17 IST LOG:  archive command failed with exit code 1
2018-04-30 16:39:17 IST DETAIL:  The failed archive command was: copy %\ip-address of sharable drive\soft\SUJITwal\000000010000000E00000083
2018-04-30 16:39:18 IST LOG:  archive command failed with exit code 1
2018-04-30 16:39:18 IST DETAIL:  The failed archive command was: copy %\ip-address of sharable drive\soft\SUJITwal\000000010000000E00000083
2018-04-30 16:39:19 IST LOG:  archive command failed with exit code 1
2018-04-30 16:39:19 IST DETAIL:  The failed archive command was: copy %\ip-address of sharable drive\soft\SUJITwal\000000010000000E00000083
2018-04-30 16:39:19 IST WARNING:  archiving transaction log file "000000010000000E00000083" failed too many times, will try again later
```

Comment: Can you also show us the error log? Do these "access denied" appear in the error log? Looks like a permission issue.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the error text

Comment: The [NetworkService account](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684272(v=vs.85).aspx), which you say is running Postgres, is unlikely to have permissions to access network resources, such as shared drives.

Comment: @mustaccio I attached a screenshot in description. If i changed network services with administration followed by youtube video then postgresql not started. What should be the step i follow for to access network sharable drive.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to correct archive_command
just replace IP-address of path to which wal files will be archived 
e.g `archive_command = 'copy "%p" "\\10.10.0.123\\soft\\\wal\\%f"'`

Also make sure the path permission is set to postgres user if not

```
chown postgres:postgres \\10.10.0.123\\soft\\\wal\\%f"'
```

If still unable to get archive files check the connection to IP may be having connection issue

Comment: There is no `chown` command in Windows

Comment: ya sorry ! he can use then properties of folder and change owneship there